# PostgreSQL config settings on dynamically created EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

Let me start by saying that I think there is a better way of doing things than I'm doing now...  so, please don't post comments and answers saying that I should be using a different technology, etc. I have a "reasonably" specific question.

A little background:

Basically, I have system where I'm processing a lot of varied, but fairly structured data feeds each day (CSV files).  It's a fairly generic ETL type of system.  I started off writing Python scripts to do it all in memory.  But, I found that I was writing a lot of code to check and enforce rules that could easily be described by a db schema.  So, I've got a of a series of SQS queue (one for each source) that has file locations (on s3) to process and a PostgreSQL db script to load to do it.  Hacky?  Yes; probably.  But, in a way, it's pretty easy to just define all of your rules in PostgreSQL.  At least for me with approx 15 years of RDBMS experience (what's that old saying about when you only have a hammer, everything looks like a nail?)

So, all works pretty well.  But, when creating EC2 instances, I have a choice of an image_id and a type/size.  I have my base "PostgreSQL worker image" that I use, but it's really geared for one size (micro).

But, now I'm thinking about trying to play around and see what kind of gains I could get if I went with small or medium.  My initial thought is that I would just created separate image_ids with a postgres conf settings geared to them.  But, seems a bit messy. (but, the whole thing is a bit messy and hacky)

*Given* what I have in place, is there a better way to accomplish this than just separate AMIs?

Final notes:

My AMIs are all PostgreSQL 9.1 and Ubuntu 12.04.  And the DBs are just temporary storage.  They only exist for the 15 or 20 minutes they are needed to load/process/output the data.

If you feel like this question could be better answered on the SE's DBA site, then please feel free to add a comment.  I usually start with StackOverflow because it's a bigger community and it's a community that I feel more at home with.  I'm much more of a developer than a DBA.

Comment: You could have the postgresql startup script recreate its config files before it launches the cluster, using metadata about the instance. (There's a teeny web service on a well-known port that will give you that metadata.)

Comment: @JamesAylett Hi. Thanks for the comment.  I know how to get the meta data for the instance.  But, I'm not sure I know how to have "postgresql startup script recreate its config files before it launches the cluster".  I've googled that phrase, but don't see anything very helpful.  Could you provide a link to the documentation or a "how-to"?

Comment: this is now somewhere between a bash question (I think postgresql still uses old-style init scripts) and a system administration question. Googling it certainly won't help; you need to understand how startup scripts work, and how to hook things into them. No documentation will help you that I'm aware of, and I'd be amazed if there's a howto. At this point I'd recommend getting a consultant in, unless someone helpful pops up here who has time to write out a full example (it's decidedly non-trivial).

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone reading this in the future, what I did was just create different AMI with different postgres conf settings.  While it might not be that elegant, it did seem to do the job.